reflexive property of congruence
While exploring basic geometry with my artist friend, she raised a question that neither of us could answer satisfactorily. Until today I thought that Hilbert's axiomatization of Euclidean geometry is a rigorous system in the sense that every true proposition about the primitive notions and relations is either stated explicitly as an axiom or proven as a theorem. The reflexive property of congruence for segments or angles however is not listed on Wikipedia's page.
I wasn't able to find its proof either. According to Wikipedia page for Congruence, it is an equivalence relation, and as such has symmetry and transitivity, in addition to reflexivity. Now, transitivity is postulated explicitly as an axiom, and according to this answer, symmetry can also be deduced from transitivity and reflexivity, but what about reflexivity itself?

My original answer was correct:
On axioms IV.I and IV.IV, Hilbert is explicit that a segment is congruent to itself and that an angle is congruent to itself.

Every segment is congruent to itself; that is, we always have
AB ≡ AB.
Every angle is congruent to itself; that is,
∠(h, k) ≡ ∠(h, k)
or
∠(h, k) ≡ ∠(k, h)


You're right. I found them in Greenberg's Geometry Chapter 3.
